# How to redefine Spring beans representation

Tags: spring, frameworks, javabeans

I would like to add extra attribute to the internal representation of beans in Spring. Is it possible? What mechanism should be applied if any?
My goal is to define my own beans for my framework. I can do it from scratch or reuse Spring mechanisms.

Comment: Do your own beans will be too spring beans?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what are you trying to achieve with your framework?

Comment: @user6617897 Can you provide an example for what you are describing so that it makes more clear for us?

Comment: Nicolas, yes, my beans are already spring beans and I would like preserve their current nature but to introduce one relatively complex attribute as well. Your answer seems to be the one I was looking for.

Comment: Another option for me is to write my own framework in pure java and implement some mechanisms already available in Spring and AspectJ. However, I prefer reusability.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the documentation [Container Extension Points](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension).

To achieve customization you can create a:

- [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) bean which operates on a bean instance. For example this allows to create a custom bean registry, to proxify...
- [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) which can operate on bean metadata. This allows `for overriding or adding properties even to eager-initializing beans`, modifying the class...
- [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) which can operate right after the registry initialization. This allows to create, remove or update beans definitions.

For example you can create a new `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` which will register (or modify) beans using a custom implementation of `BeanDefinition` which will contain custom attribute based on for example your owns annotation.

Could you elaborate a bit what are you trying to achieve with your framework?

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, my answer was too long to be just a comment - that is why I have posted it in the form of the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Merci beaucoup, Nicolas :)

I will study both your answer and the documentation you provided. I have already found the *Postprocessors you mentioned but I was not sure if this is the right place and what is the nature of their customizations (subclassing or something different) and what are the consequences. My problem is not as simple as I told (not just adding an attribute) - the extended Spring bean should be used also in cooperation to Spring+AspectJ (not SpringAOP), especially with declare-parents construct. I would like to be able to create proxies for the redefined beans as well. I will let you know what are the results of my investigation and may be I will ask some questions.

And the answer to all of you:
My framework is dedicated to defining graph modeling languages (meta-models) at run-time (being far extension of OMG standards) and I am looking for solutions of limits introduced by current object representation in JVM, which promotes behaviour over structure. This is one of several approaches, but the most prospective for me due to the relatively small effort.